# How to filter users first name from related model in Django filter form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I want to filter users first name from my profile model using [Django filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) 
this is my profile model in ***models.py***.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_members = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    ...other fields
```

and this is my ***filters.py***

```
import django_filters
from .models import Profile

class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

in this when I add my form to template it gives me select tag with all users username and I don't want that because if user want to filter user by it's name than they can search by their name instead of looking in drop down.
Please help me (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution I just added a filed in my Django filter form and access related filed by **Double Underscore (Name Mangling)**
`user__first_name`
this is changed version of my code

```
import django_filters
from .models import Profile

class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        label="First Name",
        field_name="user__first_name",
        lookup_expr='icontains',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'First Name',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'type': 'text'
        })
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', ...other fields]
```